# Expected result of a custom dice

Tags: probability, expected-value

Imagine a 6 sided dice but numbers are 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 2 - 3.
I know the concept of bell curve and in fact, I wrote all possible outcomes for throwing a coin 4 times and there really was a bell curve and the most probable/expected result was 2 head and 2 tails.

But my brain got really weird when I tried to prove myself that in a dice like I mentioned, if we roll it 18 times, most probable/expect result  would be around 12 number 1's, 3 number 2's and 3 number 3's. I just know it has to be, but I just can't prove it

Can someone prove me or prove me otherwise?

Comment: $1-1-1-2-3$ is only five numbers.

Comment: @lulu you are right, let me edit it

Comment: You write "most probable/expected result". These are not generally the same, at least if you mean expected in the sense of expected value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different concepts here, "expected value" (the mean) and "most probable outcome" (the mode).

The mean is not so difficult: the expected value from one roll, given the die is fair, is just the average of the values, $(1+1+1+1+2+3)/6=1.5$. Expectation is linear, so the expected value from $18$ rolls is $1.5\times 18=27$. If we unpack that calculation a bit by reminding ourselves of where $1.5$ came from, we get $((1+1+1+1+2+3)/6)\times 18=(1+1+1+1+2+3)\times 3=1\times 12+2\times 3+3\times 3$, which is where your intuition of "$12$ ones, $3$ twos and $3$ threes" is coming from.

The mode is more complicated. We can use a little bit of ad hoc reasoning that should remind you of the binomial distribution to calculate the exact probability of getting $12$ ones, $3$ twos and $3$ threes, by noticing that the probability of getting a one is $4/6$ and a two and three are $1/6$ chance each. We multiply the probability of getting the right number of each dice by the number of orders the dice could come in:

$$ \mathbb{P}(\text{12 ones, 3 twos, 3 threes})=\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{12}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{3}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{3}\times {18\choose 12}{6\choose 3}{3\choose 3}=0.0613...$$

But, if we want to prove that this is the mode, such calculations are not going to be so useful and we need a different reasoning relating to bell curves. Take a look at the [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution), which is the distribution we have here, with parameters $n=18$ trials and probabilities of each outcome $4/6,1/6,1/6$.